# No module named 'python_agent_utils' while running python agent for hyperledger indy setup

Tags: python, docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I tried to run the indy agent using docker on Ubuntu 16.04 from here: [https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-agent/tree/master/python][1]

I already build the docker image by using this command:

```
 make docker-build
```

But when i try to run the next command:

```
 make docker-start PORT=8094
```

i get this error:

```
make docker-start PORT=8094
docker run -it -p $PORT:$PORT -e PORT=$PORT --name indy-agent_$PORT indy-agent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "indy-agent.py", line 20, in <module>
    from modules.connection import Connection, AdminConnection
  File "/app/modules/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from python_agent_utils.messages.errors import ValidationException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_agent_utils'
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same error, please help and @Trinayan if you find anything then please answer it.